# How do I get %LocalAppData% in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get `%LocalAppData%` in C#?

Comment: You didn't provide much information in your question, and I don't know if you're talking about VisualStudio the software, or one of the languages it uses - like C# or VisualBasic.NET.

Comment: Dee, please change the accepted answer, the most-voted one is better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData")` for C#, since Visual Studio isn't a language, unless you're looking to get that variable in one of the VS dialogs or something.

Comment: I have edited my post.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") for C# works.
Thanks

Answer (score 205):

If you would like to use an enumeration, call [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Using this technique, you can also find all other Windows' [special folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) (i.e Program Files, My Documents, etc).

Comment: Yup, it's possible for the env var to be overridden, but this call will always return the same thing for a given user

Comment: @JoshK That's an argument for using the env var in many situations IMO

Comment: Thanks I wasn't even aware there was a constant for this.