# Store user-specific data under windows

Tags: c#, windows

I have an application that needs to store user-specific data. Currently I use the userprofile to store the data:

```
C:\Users\<username>\
```

Now I have the problem that the data gets to big and some users get an error because the file size exceeds the user profile size.

Changing the user profile size is not an option.

So I would need one of the following solutions:
1. Mark the data/folder somehow as "keep local"
2. Use another folder that exists in windows that is user-specific
3. Create some local folder and mark it as "this is only for user xyz"

Is any of these three solutions available?

(The clients are on windows 7 and above if this is of importance)

Code to determine the folder:

```
  string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
  string folder = Path.Combine(userPath, PlaylistsFolder);
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us your code.

Comment: There are different locations for roaming and local profiles. Where do you store the data? Is there a restriction for *local* user data too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get %LocalAppData% in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980105/how-do-i-get-localappdata-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by replacing `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` with `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`

Comment: This is a 50% duplicate of the answer suggested. Only 50% because understanding that LocalApplicationData does not have this issue is part of the solution. That's why I suggest this question is kept for future generations ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to create data on a non-user specific location, you can apply solution three by creating a root folder and then subfolders based on the logged-in username. Unfortunately of cause this poses the question if the stored data are sensitive, then you should do some encryption to make sure users can't access and modify another user's data.

You can retrieve logged in user's name like this:

```
string userName = null;
using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = 
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
   userName = identity.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, could you create a new user specific folder within your applications %ProgramData% folder, and then in the c:\User\[username] folder, create a SymLink to it?

About SymLinks, see here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/